# bootstrap4 accordion not working inside ngFor by passing index

Tags: html, accordion

i am using bootstrap 4 accordion inside ngFor  , I am passing index to the data-target element and to the id , the ids are coming different but accordion is not working, since it is not working with dynamic for loop, below is the code , can any one please help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card mb-2" *ngFor="let list of workOrderList; let i=index">
        <div class="card-header bg-white" id="heading0">
            <h6 class="mb-0">
                <a type="button" class="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse0">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{list?.awoNumber}}</a>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse0" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading0" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the standard markup language for describing the
            structure of web pages.
                <a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There's a `</div>` missing at the very end. Might that be the cause? Or copy/ paste mistake?

Comment: copy paste mistake , it is not working even div is closed